# How can tornado use pipe to async send data to client?

Tags: python, tornado, tar, data-synchronization

With the tornado I use multiprocessing to create a child process to do the compressing work. And the child process directly send data to main process via `os.pipe`

Right, now the problem is `self.stream.read_until_close` block the call, and it does not `tar_worker` close the other side of the pipe.

My code list below:

```
def tar_worker(fd, path):
    '''Tar worker to do the compressing work, directly write data to pipe.'''
    fp = os.fdopen(fd, 'w')
    tar = tarfile.open(mode='w|', fileobj=fp, dereference=True)
    tar.add(path)
    tar.close()
    fp.close()


class getTarFileHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        recv, sender = os.pipe()
        self.p = multiprocessing.Process(target=tar_worker, args=(sender, '/boot/'))
        self.p.start()
        self.fd = recv

        # Create PipeIOStream
        self.stream = tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream(self.fd)
        self.stream.read_until_close(callback=self.f, streaming_callback=self.send_data)


    def f(self, s):
        print 'done send work'
        self.finish() #close connection

    def send_data(self, chunk):
        self.write(chunk)
        self.flush()
```

Comment: You use `@gen.coroutine`, but then use callbacks instead of `yield`. You need to remove the `@coroutine` decorator or replace the callbacks with `yield`. There is also a typo: you set `self.fd = recv` but use `self.fp` when creating the `PipeIOStream`.

Comment: I replace the callback to yield `self.stream.read_until_close(callback=self.f, streaming_callback=self.send_data)` and add `self.f()` under this line, but still not close the connection.

Comment: Don't use a `callback=` argument when using `yield` (but you *do* want to use a callback for `streaming_callback`): `yield self.stream.read_until_close(streaming_callback=self.send_data)`. It's often more idiomatic in coroutines to use a loop with `data = yield self.stream.read_bytes(chunk_size, partial=True)`.

Comment: I found this bug maybe not relate to tornado, is a os pipe problem? I do `r, w=os.pipe()` and set `r` to unblocked, and close `w`, then `os.read(r, 10)` return `''` instead of raise `errno.EBADF`

Comment: You should not expect `EBADF` in this case. The read and write ends of a pipe are closed independently, so `r` is still open even after `w` is closed. `read()` returns an empty string when you have reached the end of the pipe.

Comment: yes, that right. But in this case, how to let `self.stream` know if reached the end of the pipe. Right now, `data = yield self.stream.read_bytes` still yield when reach the end of pipe

Comment: `yield self.stream.read_bytes()` will raise `iostream.StreamClosedError` when the stream is closed.

Comment: Here is my full test code, https://gist.github.com/tywtyw2002/3744b7eaf0dbf2923e5f. I try many way to modify it, but it always block in line 85 when reached the end of pipe. I do diff between the data that received and origian, there no different.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I've reproduced the problem and have written up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File handles can be shared across multiple processes; in this case both the parent and child processes have file descriptors pointing to *both ends* of the same underlying pipe. Both the parent and child process must close `sender` for it to be truly closed. After starting the `multiprocessing.Process`, the parent process must do `os.close(sender)` to close its copy of the writing end of the pipe. This will not prevent the child process from writing to its copy; once both parent and child have closed their copies of the writing end of the pipe, the reading end of the pipe will report EOF and the IOStream read methods will raise StreamClosedError.